# Reordering image skeleton coordinates to make interp1d work better

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scikit-image

For a school project I'm analyzing the centerlines of some *C. elegans* images. I've managed to generate a reasonable threshold and I'm using `skimage.morphology.skeletonize` to generate the centerline:

[image]

Then I use `np.nonzero` to get the coordinates of the centerline with the eventual goal of parametrizing these points to gain some insight into the centerline geometry.

However, when I use `scipy.interpolate.interp1d`, I get this mess:
[image]
I'm fairly sure this happens because when `np.nonzero` looks for the nonzero values, it goes bottom-up and right-left and orders the points as such, which is why I get the zig-zag effect during interpolation. Is there any way that I can reorder these points so that `interp1d` plays nice with them?

Here is my code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy import ndimage
from scipy import stats
from scipy import misc
from skimage.morphology import skeletonize
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

"""Curved Worm"""

img = misc.imread("model_image_crop_curved.tif")
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()

imgThresh = img>200
plt.imshow(imgThresh)
plt.show()

misc.imsave('model_image_crop_curved_binary.tif',imgThresh)

imgSkel = skeletonize(imgThresh)
plt.imshow(imgSkel)
plt.show()
misc.imsave('model_image_crop_curved_skeleton.tif',imgSkel)

cv2Skel = cv2.imread('model_image_crop_curved_skeleton.tif',cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

skelCoord = np.nonzero(imgSkel)

x = skelCoord[1]
y = skelCoord[0]

plt.plot(x,y,'.')
plt.show()

i = np.arange(len(x))
interp_i = np.linspace(0,i.max(),5*i.max())

interpKind = 'linear'

xi = interp1d(i,x,kind=interpKind)(interp_i)
yi = interp1d(i,y,kind=interpKind)(interp_i)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(xi,yi,'b-')
ax.plot(x,y,'ko')
plt.show()
```

And here are the points I get from `np.nonzero`:

```
[51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 45 46 47 48 49 50 68 69
 70 71 72 73 74 75 40 41 42 43 44 76 77 78 36 37 38 39 79 80 34 35 32 33 31
 30 30 29 28 28 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 26 26 26 26 26 26 27 27 27 27 27 27
 27 28 28 29 30 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49
 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 56]
[16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17
 17 17 17 17 17 17 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 19 19 19 19 19 19 20 20 21 21 22
 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47
 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 58 59 59 60 61 61 61 62 62 62 63 64 64 65
 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72]
```

**EDIT**

To solve the ordering problem, I followed ev-br's suggestion and began with the end points. I used a series of possible end point orientations and the `ndimage.binary_hit_or_miss` function to isolate the end points. Then I wrote a function that walked down the skeleton by checking each pixel's neighbors for the next in the skeleton, moving to that one, and keeping a running list. This running list became the set of ordered points I was looking for.

However, once I accomplished this after many hours of frustration (including an entire half hour spent agonizing over a problem that was easily solved by replacing `and` with `or` in one of my `if` statements), I realized that when I interpolate these data points they really don't provide much additional information. Since the data points I collected by walking along the skeleton are parametric in themselves, any parametric analysis I do can use those points. So while it is good that I figured out how to order the points, interpolation didn't turn out to be the end goal anyways.

If anyone wants to see the code I wrote to accomplish this, send me a message and I'll gladly share.

Comment: Could you add one image? Or link a public one like from wikipedia, that you code could apply to?

Comment: @roadrunner66 the image that I'm using is the first one in my question. It's called 'model_image_crop_curved_skeleton.tif' in the code and I use cv2 to read it as cv2Skel. I've posted it as a PNG because Stack Overflow doesn't like TIF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you noticed, you need to order the nonzero pixels. Since you've skeletonized the image, you can start from an endpoint (whixh has exactly one neighbor) and walk along the path until you reach the other one. This way, you get an ordered list of pixel coordinates, which you then interpolate. Notice though that the question of how to parameterize a curve is not trivial, and you might need to do things beyond just tossing in `interp1d`

One keyword for searching the internet is "analyze skeleton".

Answer (score 1):

Rather than doing 1D interpolation, try 2D.  That's what your data actually represent, and SciPy already has a function to do it:

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp2d.html

Comment: I'm looking into using this function, but it's difficult. There are plenty of examples on how to use it for gridded data, but I'm just looking to fit a curve to multivariate unstructured data. I see pictures of results like that, but no associated explanations.

Comment: To better explain this, I would like to do something similar to what this person is asking: https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-fit-the-best-2D-spline-to-some-scattered-data-in-Python